# Iterating through Dynamic variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables table_Day and table_A

table_Day

| I | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-02-2021 |
| 2 | 05-03-2021 |
| 3 | 05-04-2021 |
| 4 | 05-05-2021 |
| 5 | 05-06-2021 |

and so on. It goes till 365 days

Table_B

| Cust | Added_Date | Bill No | Cust_Setup_Dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 05-03-2021 | 1A | 05-03-2021 |
| Mark | 05-03-2021 | 1P | 05-03-2021 |
| Dave | 05-03-2021 | 35B | 05-03-2021 |
| Joan | 05-03-2021 | 40C | 05-03-2021 |
| Mark | 05-04-2021 | 2A | 05-03-2021 |
| Mark | 05-04-2021 | 54A | 05-03-2021 |
| Mark | 05-04-2021 | 88A | 05-03-2021 |
| Phil | 05-04-2021 | 3Z | 05-04-2021 |
| Joan | 05-04-2021 | 2D | 05-03-2021 |
| Joan | 05-04-2021 | 57L | 05-03-2021 |
| Mark | 05-05-2021 | 10E | 05-03-2021 |
| STUK | 05-05-2021 | 12F | 05-05-2021 |
| WILL | 05-05-2021 | 20ER | 05-05-2021 |

and so on.
I need to find the cumulative count of bills for each customer for each day, upto that day. The sample output would look something like this

| Cust | Day | Cumulative Count of Bills |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 05-03-2021 | 2 |
| Mark | 05-04-2021 | 5 |
| Mark | 05-05-2021 | 6 |
| Joan | 05-03-2021 | 1 |
| Joan | 05-04-2021 | 3 |

Here, on day 1 Mark had only 2 bills. On day 2, Mark had 3 bills, so total cumulative count becomes Count of (Day1 + Day2) = 5. On day 3 total count becomes (count(day 1 + day 2 + day 3)) = 6 and so on. Need to do this for all customers. Current code which I have is logically correct, but because of the size of data (table_A has billions of data points across hundreds of rows and columns) and table_Day is for 365 days. Computationally it is extremely time consuming.

```
with table_Day (I, DT) AS 
(
  SELECT 1, SYSDATE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
 SELECT I + 1, DT - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM Dates_Index WHERE I < 365
)

select A.cust,A.count(distinct (A.Bill_No)) as cul_count,A.Added_Date,A.cust_setup_dt,D.DT
from table_Day D
cross join lateral 
table_A A
WHERE a.ADDED_DATE between (A.Cust_setup_dt) and (D.DT)
group by A.cust,D.DT,A.Added_Date
```

This code takes too much time that it is not feasible computationally. Since the cumulative count is basically just count of all bills till previous day + current day, iterating through the table for all Added_Date for every Day in table_Day seems doing same processes again and again. Instead I was thinking to store the cumulative count in a temporary variable and update it by adding the count of the current day to the number already stored. I want the logic to be something like this.

```
for cust = x (where x = 1 to n)

(Declare @temp_cul_count = 0
Declare @temp_added_date


    (for i = 05-02-2021 to (05-06-2021) 
     cul_count = count(distinct(bills)
     temp_cul_count = temp_cul_count + cul_count
     print(cul_count),print(table_day.DAY) /*Basically storing the updated cul_count and day in table*/
     i++
     if i > a.added_date
     break)
)
x++
```

The above code is basic logic which I want to implement. However, I have no idea how to put it in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to join your calendar for each customer and then find the cumulative total with the `SUM` analytic function:

```sql
WITH calendar (day) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 12)
)
select A.cust,
       C.day,
       SUM(COALESCE(bill_count, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY a.cust ORDER BY C.day)
         AS cum_bill_count
from   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT cust,
                added_date,
                COUNT(DISTINCT bill_no) AS bill_count
         FROM   table_a
         GROUP BY
                cust,
                added_date
       ) a
       PARTITION BY (a.cust)
       ON (c.day = a.added_date)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0ea9d560fdcdf60e2c52114631a3f559)*

Comment: It works well. However would you know how to do it in Dynamic Sql with variables? That is just for learning.

Comment: @Rogue258 In general you do not; Oracle is not the same as SQL Server and if you are going to be context switching from SQL queries to PL/SQL, where you work with variables, then the continual context switches will make it orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Additionally, I cannot think of any way to do it efficiently in PL/SQL (you would need to loop through a cursor to get the users, then have another loop for dates and then have a nested query inside the loop to calculate the total per day and you've gone from the single SQL query in the answer to many queries in nested loops... no thanks).